# Legacy Project Migrated to Hibernate 5.6 (Java 16) Has Slow one-to-one bidirectional Performance

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, one-to-one

I am migrating a legacy hibernate project from version 4.3 (with Java 11) to 5.6 (with Java 16). The HBM files below map an object graph of **Jurisdiction -> Unit -> UnitAux**. Units are lazy-loaded, and UnitAux is one-to-one with Unit. Under version 4.3, when initiazing Units, it would take about 100ms to load. Under version 5.6, it now takes 600-800ms.

These are the abbreviated HBM files for the 3 entities:

**Jurisdiction.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.edc.c2c.core.model.impl.Jurisdiction" table="Jurisdiction" schema="domain" dynamic-update="true">
    
    <set name="units" 
        inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select" 
        optimistic-lock="false" batch-size="1000" where="recordStatus = 'A'">
        <key>
            <column name="jurisdictionId"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.edc.c2c.core.model.impl.Unit"/>
    </set>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Unit.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.edc.c2c.core.model.impl.Unit" table="Unit" schema="domain" dynamic-update="false">
  
  <composite-id>
        <key-property name="id"                   column="id"             type="long"/>
        <key-property name="owningJurisdictionId" column="jurisdictionId" type="long"/>
    </composite-id>
    
    <one-to-one name="unitAux" class="com.edc.c2c.core.model.impl.UnitAux" cascade="all" fetch="join" property-ref="unit"/>
  
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**UnitAux.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.edc.c2c.core.model.impl.UnitAux" table="UnitAux" schema="domain" dynamic-update="true">
  
  <composite-id>
        <key-property name="id"             column="id"             type="long"/>
        <key-property name="jurisdictionId" column="jurisdictionId" type="long"/>
    </composite-id>
    
    <many-to-one name="unit" class="com.edc.c2c.core.model.impl.Unit" unique="true" not-null="true" 
        cascade="all" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="id"/>
        <column name="jurisdictionId"/>
    </many-to-one>
    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If I comment out the one-to-one in **Unit.hbm.xml**, the unit(s) Set loads fast, as expected.

In the UnitAux.hbm.xml, I replaced the many-to-one with a bag containing a one-to-many, something like this:

```
<bag name="unitGroup" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select">
  <key>
      <column name="id"/>
      <column name="jurisdictionId"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="com.edc.c2c.core.model.impl.unit"/>
</bag>
```

With this, the UnitAux class had a List property called unitGroup. With the bag, the unit(s) load time dropped to 300ms.

I'm at a loss as to how to get the hibernate 5.6 to perform at the same load times as 4.3.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I forgot to mention, both versions effectively produce the same SQL. Something about how the objects themselves are initialized must be causing the slow down.

**Update 2:** The session statistics between 4.3 and 5.6 were very similar; not enough to explain the performance difference. My investigation has shown that the delays appear to be centered around initializing the entities. Specifically, the call to

```
Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections( final List hydratedObjects, final Object resultSetId, final SharedSessionContractImplementor session, final boolean readOnly, List<AfterLoadAction> afterLoadActions)
```

The time spent here is where the latency lies. Every property in each entity is tested for bytecode enhancement. In my test, I'm loading 600+ Units, along with the 600+ UnitAux entities. Is than an alternate loader that doesn't do this?

**Update 3:** Changing the association for Unit -> UnitAux to unidirectional reduced the latency by roughly half. Now it's only 3x slower.

**Update 4:** This is very strange. After experimenting with a variety of things, I made the following discovery. If I enable logging at the INFO (or ERROR) level for hibernate (see below config), everything runs fast, at the expected timing:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

If logging isn't declared, it runs slow (meaning nothing is specifically configured for hibernate). Is this something peculiar with jboss logging? I'm using jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar. Does it run slower if nothing is explicitly declared in the log4j.xml? It's like the classic problem of having debug statements that never get used, but Java has to build all of the string values, which leads to extreme latency.

**Update 5:** I just did a spot check of the source code for Hibernate Core 5.6.0-Final. 141 classes use log.trace, and there are 249 class that use log.debug. Most of the log.trace calls don't pre-check to see if TRACE is enabled. The log.debug calls are checked more frequently, but there are stil a ton that don't pre-check to see if DEBUG is enabled.

Comment: I changed some of the narrative to point out that the migration also involves going from JDK 11 to JDK 16, in case that is relevant.

Comment: With regard to **Update 5**, my tests were initially done with log4j1-2.16. When I switched over to logback and slf4j-1.7.5 (no log4j) for the same tests, the times were fast as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I found my own answer to this problem.

First, there was no problem at all with Hibernate 5.x and one-to-one bidirectional associations. The problem had everything to do with debug/trace logging. With Hibernate 5.x and bytecode enhancement, a lot of new logging was added. Not only is logging done for each row-wise entity, but also for each column/property (testing for column lazy loading?).

Second, my entity classes have special formatting for toString(). Invocations of these toString()s can take a lot of time to execute, and then multiply if over hundreds of entities.

Third, there must be some bug between jboss-logging and log4j1-12.x. Internally, jboss-logging#doLogf() checks for whether or not the logging level is enabled, however, it is still reaching the String formatter. Here is a snapshot from VisualVM with the application running in Tomcat; you can see that 700ms was added for debug formatting, even though it would never be printed out to the log file:

[image: VisualVM CPU Sample Snapshot - Tomcat 9]

If the Hibernate code had debug/trace level checks before the logging calls, this would not happen.

In the end, with Tomcat, I removed all log4j and slf4j-log4j jar files. That solved the problem.